# How to print Hello World in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

I downloaded the library file which is Irvine32, then I create my assembly program in Visual Studio empty project. I'm new to assembly language. Below is my code.

```
.386

.model flat, stdcall

.stack 4096

ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
msg  db "Hello again, World!",0
.code

main Proc



    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?

Comment: My OS is window10

Comment: What is your question? You are not referencing `msg` anywhere.

Comment: @ecm What is the syntax to reference the message?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with it. For example, `mov esi, offset msg` is I think the Microsoft MASM syntax to set up the `esi` register to point to the message, if that is what you want.

Comment: okk I already made it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Example code below for a Windows console program using Visual Studio's native library rather than the Irvine library. Visual Studio 2015 and later versions inline printf into the compiled code, normally requiring a C source file with main(), but this can be avoided by using legacy library (which includes scanf, printf, ... ).

Visual Studio may not setup a default build for .asm files. In this case, right click on the .asm file name in the solution explorer windows, then properties. Set excluded from build to no, item type to custom build tool, and apply. Then from custom build tool window, using x.asm as the name of the file:

```
command line:  ml /c /Zi /Fo$(OutDir)\x.obj x.asm
...
output file:   $(OutDir)\x.obj
```

Do this for both debug and release builds. For release builds, the /Zi is not needed:

```
command line:  ml /c /Fo$(OutDir)\x.obj x.asm
```

Example code:

```
        .686p                   ;enable instructions
        .xmm                    ;enable instructions
        .model flat,c           ;use C naming convention (stdcall is default)

;       include C libraries
        includelib      msvcrtd
        includelib      oldnames
        includelib      legacy_stdio_definitions.lib    ;for scanf, printf, ...

        .data                   ;initialized data
msg     db      "Hello again, World!",00dh,00ah,000h    ;added CR, LF to msg

        .data?                  ;uinitialized data

        .stack  4096            ;stack (optional, linker will default)

        .code                   ;code 
        extrn   printf:near
        public  main

main    proc
        push    offset msg
        call    printf
        add     esp,4
        xor     eax,eax
        ret
main    endp

        end
```

Comment: from i understand is using the vs native library file need to memorize the syntax.

Comment: But I already made it also `mov edx, OFFSET msg` then `call WriteString`

Comment: @彭政斌 - I don't have or know what Irvine.inc includes.

Comment: oh, it just a library file for MASM, you can download it on GitHub if you need it. By the way, thank you so much.